# Database Handler SQLlite Version issue

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have one quote application which have sqllite database. I have published first version of application which have not any field for database version. Now I need to republish application with database version=1. I am trying my self for use this code but getting issue of copy data. If I want update application which have database version 1, which condition should I apply so old user who have installed application without database version field and new user also not face any issue ?
My database handler class is like below.
Thanks

```html
   public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH;
private static String DB_NAME = "SuccessQuotes";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  
  public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

 super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 this.myContext = context;
 DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
 Log.e("path", DB_PATH);
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

 boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

 if (dbExist) {

 } else {

  this.getReadableDatabase();

  try {

   copyDataBase();

  } catch (IOException e) {

   throw new Error("Error copying database");

  }
 }

}

// ==============================================================================

private boolean checkDataBase() {

 SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

 try {
  String myPath = DB_PATH;
  checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

 } catch (SQLiteException e) {

  // database does't exist yet.

 }

 if (checkDB != null) {

  checkDB.close();

 }

 return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

// ==============================================================================

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

 // Open your local db as the input stream
 InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

 // Path to the just created empty db
 String outFileName = DB_PATH;

 // Open the empty db as the output stream
 OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

 // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int length;
 while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
  myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
 }

 // Close the streams
 myOutput.flush();
 myOutput.close();
 myInput.close();

}

// ==============================================================================

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

 // Open the database
 String myPath = DB_PATH;
 myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

// ==============================================================================

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

 if (myDataBase != null)
  myDataBase.close();

 super.close();

}

// ==============================================================================

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

// ==============================================================================

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Comment: not getting your problem..

Comment: If you want to take copy of previous version of database then do it in `onUpgrade` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper`...

Comment: I want update application which have not any field of database version. Now I want update application with database version=1, what should I change in code located above ? I am new in sqllite database and android.

Comment: means you didn't declare `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` in previous application.

Comment: hi ! I have declared it, but in database file I have not created any filed with version 1. It should not necessary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database version is automatically stored by the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

When your `DATABASE_VERSION` value is larger than the version currently stored in the database, `onUpgrade` will automatically be called at the first open attempt (by `getWritableDatabase()`).